# Adding foreign key data to serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the Django Rest-Framework to produce some JSON that shows all the user's posts, but also shows the images for that post. Image is a foreign key to Post. Here are the models:

**models.py**

```
  class Post(models.Model):
        user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        status          = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    class Image(models.Model):
        post        = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        img         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        views_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
class GetPosts(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        requested_user = get_requested_user(self)
        return Post.objects.filter(user=requested_user).order_by('-created_at')

def get_requested_user(self):
    filter_kwargs = {'username': self.kwargs['username']}
    return get_object_or_404(User.objects.all(), **filter_kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_img = serializers.RelatedField(source='Image', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('status', 'image_img ')
```

In the serializers.py, I'd like to show **all** of the fields for Image (`img, views_count`) What I get with my current code is this:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "status": "I am number 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which contains the user's posts, but not the user's posts and each post's images. Note: Query url looks like this: /api/posts/user/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ***Nested serializer*** here,

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('img',)


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_img = ImageSerializer(source='image_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Hence the response will be like,

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "status": "I am number 1",
            "image_img": [
                {"img": "image_url"},
                {"img": "image_url"},
                ....
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> How to display **`all`** field of model class in serializer?

From the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include),

> You can also set the **`fields`** attribute to the special value **`'__all__'`** to indicate that ***all fields in the model should be used***.

**Reference**
1. [DRF- Nested Realtions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)
2. [**`source`** argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)
3. [Specifying which fields to include](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I wanted to get all of Post's fields instead of just status?

Comment: update **`fields=__all__`** in `Meta` class of `PostSerializer`